# Cannot select Typescript as a language in VSCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use vscode and typescript. I have typescript installed globally. When trying to select the file language for proper syntax highlighting typescript is not listed. I have tried uninstalling vscode and reinstalling it, as well as disabling all extensions.

Currently I have prettier enabled, however since I can't select Typescript as a language, the syntax highlighting is none, or it makes things red since it isn't detecting that its typescript.

[No syntax highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Z5nG.png)
[image: file language extension selection screen]

[Language selected is Javascript and Typescript syntax is highlighted red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ij5tz.png)

Comment: if the file has extension `.ts` you get languageID TypeScript no need to install anything, it even works if you don't have TypeScript installed

Comment: But it doesn't work. It highlights a lot of syntax Red

Comment: @Dan ok that is definitely weird. what type file does it show for extension `.ts`

Comment: @UdenduAbasili It doesn't have anything resembling typescript. The screen shot doesn't show me typing anything because the list is empty if I type "ty". There are options like React Javascript, so I did double check that it's not listed as React Typescript, etc.  I tried uninstalling and reinstalling, but it saved my extensions when I redownloaded, so I am going to try to find out how to uninstall completely and delete any cached info like that.

Comment: @dan raise the issue on github for VS Code. you should use try to redownload the VS Code as typescript file type detection comes by default

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It sounds like you've disabled the built-in JS/TS extension (or potentially have another extension overriding it).

In the extensions view, search `@builtin TypeScript` and make sure `TypeScript Language Basics` is enabled:

[image: Enabling TS language basics]

`TypeScript Language Basics` provides syntax highlighting while `TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features` provides intellisense.

Comment: That fixed my problem, thank you! Typescript Language Basics was not enabled.